# Team Foundation Server - Eclipse and Cross Platform: Unable to clone Git repository using TEE in Eclipse. Error cloning - Not Authorized

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I have TFS 2018.2 and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version 2019-06 (4.12.0). In eclipse I have installed Team Explorer Everywhere plugin and I am able to see all my Git repository however when I try to clone a git repository using the administrator account in TFS I get below error:

> Error cloning the `<GitName>` repository.
>   `http://../..//<GitName>`: not authorized.

Clone Error:

[image]

Eclipse Version:

[image]

[Reference Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/labs/eclipsegit/?view=azure-devops)

In case if the question is placed in the wrong forum path feel free to correct it.

I have tried the resolution provided in https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere#frequently-asked-questions-faq

Also, tried installing latest versions of Egit in Eclipse - https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/

I am not sure how to use the older version of Egit to try the import of repository. I seem to have latest version of Egit.

UPDATE:
Apparently I am able to resolve the issue by following below steps:

[image]

And creating a Git repository from File menu and then utilizing the 'Copy clone URL' from the first image. Select the newly created repository and perform right click on it to select  'Paste repository path or url' which would ask for authentication and repo would be copied.

However the action items have carried TFS to run into issues:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Hi  Ahetejazahmad Khan. Any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I'm afraid you are in the wrong direction to fix this issue.

Your error actually is "not authorized" which is not **Authentication not supported**. There are totally different issues. Instead of digging into that QA, you should try to figure out why it's not authorized for MyGit repository.

First give a try to use Eclipse with version 4.2 to 4.6 instead of latest according to official link of [team-explorer-everywhere](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere#frequently-asked-questions-faq%20lso).

> Supported on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. Compatible with IDEs that
>   are based on Eclipse 4.2 to 4.6.

Besides follow below steps to narrow down the issue:

1. You should also use git command line by using the administrator
   account in TFS and check if you are able to use it to connect/clone
   MyGit repository which hosted by TFS server.
2. Check if your Eclipse can connect to and clone library from any
   GitHub repo correctly.
3. Update or delete cached credentials  from Control Panel ->
   Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials  the password for
   `git:http://ServerName:xx/`